# How to cast random numbers in an array?

Tags: c++, random, casting

I'm currently trying to create 20 random numbers in an array and set these values to either 0 or 1. The problem I'm having after this is when I try to do a bit of casting to try and get these numbers to doubles. From what I understand (Not much), this should work, but it just outputs 0's and 1's again. I'd really appreciate any help or advice.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int array[20] = { 0 };

   for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
   {
      array[j] = rand() % 2;

      cout << (double)array[j] << endl;
  }
```

}

Comment: Yes, what you describe is what this code does. What do you want it to do?

Comment: On re-reading, is the problem that the **output** doesn't have decimal points? That's the default form of output: the values don't have any fractional part, so there's nothing to show. I'm sure there's a comprehensive answer for that, but for now, try `std::cout << std::fixed << (double)array[j] << '\n';`.

Answer (score -1):

The "% 2" that you have after rand() will give only 1 and 0. The ‘%’ operator returns the remainder when first operand is divided by the second. Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operators-in-c-set-1-arithmetic-operators/)

Comment: But producing 1 and 0 is exactly what the question says the code is supposed to do. You can't answer this question as it stands, because the question doesn't clearly say what the desired result is.

Comment: I'm sorry i was thinking that the he didn't want the code to output 1 and 0. Will read more carefully next time.